# WebGL with GPU accelleration in Docker container or cloud service

Tags: docker, cloud, gpu, webgl, x11

I am trying to deploy WebGL application on a cloud service. My application is made in three.js and puppeteer and it works as an API, in which user sends a request with JSON as parameter and as a response a screenshot of a scene is returned to the user.

I tried to make this app work inside of Docker container, and I managed to make it work by passing access to hosts X server and DISPLAY env variable as additional parameters to `docker run` command, but I didn't find any cloud service that allows to call `docker run` command manually with parameters or that gives access to X and DISPLAY.

I created [this GitHub repo to easily reproduce this issue](https://github.com/allala0/docker-webgl).

This repo consists of a simple WebGL application inside of headless Chrome which runs some tests that are checking if WebGL is GPU Accelerated and if scene is rendered properly. This test app is made with Puppeteer (to run and control Google Chrome) and three.js (WebGL wrapper).

I am able to successfully run the code with GPU acceleration if I forward XServer and DISPLAY:

```
# Build Docker image and run it with XServer and DISPLAY forwarding
sudo docker build -f Dockerfile . -t $USER/docker-webgl
xhost +local:
sudo docker run -it --rm --net=host -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" -v /dev/dri:/dev/dri --security-opt=label=type:container_runtime_t -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY $USER/docker-webgl:latest
```

But I am not able to run the code with GPU acceleration without passing extra parameters:

```
sudo docker build -f Dockerfile . -t $USER/docker-webgl
sudo docker run -it --rm --net=host $USER/docker-webgl:latest
```

Is there any way of making OpenGL/WebGL work with GPU accelleration inside of Docker container that has no access to X server and DISPLAY?

If that is not possible, is there any cloud service that allows running OpenGL/WebGL with GPU acceleration?

Comment: I don't think there's any cloud providers running X11 on the host.